# PHPmailer no me funciona al enviar un correo (Troubleshooting)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, gmail

Hola buenas llevo dándole vueltas mirando información y no encuentro manera ninguna de que me funcione el enviar este correo a piñón al correo deseado, y no sé por qué me da este fallo,
He desactivado el firewall, estoy haciendo la petición en postman por si tendría algo que ver que a mi parecer no debería de afectar en nada el postman.

Agradeceria que alguien me echara una manilla en este jaleo que tengo.

Gracias de antemano.

```
                /*Lo primero es añadir al script la clase phpmailer desde la ubicación en que esté*/
                require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';
                require 'PHPMailer/class.smtp.php';
                require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

                //Crear una instancia de PHPMailer
                $mail = new PHPMailer();
                //Definir que vamos a usar SMTP
                $mail->IsSMTP();
                //Esto es para activar el modo depuración. En entorno de pruebas lo mejor es 2, en producción siempre 0
                // 0 = off (producción)
                // 1 = client messages
                // 2 = client and server messages

                $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
                //Ahora definimos gmail como servidor que aloja nuestro SMTP
                $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
                //El puerto será el 587 ya que usamos encriptación TLS
                $mail->Port       = 587;
                //Definmos la seguridad como TLS
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
                //Tenemos que usar gmail autenticados, así que esto a TRUE
                $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
                //Definimos la cuenta que vamos a usar. Dirección completa de la misma
                $mail->Username   = "EmailQueHePuesto@gmail.com";
                //Introducimos nuestra contraseña de gmail
                $mail->Password   = "ContraseñaDelEmailQueHePuesto";
                //Definimos el remitente (dirección y, opcionalmente, nombre)
                $mail->SetFrom('EmailQueHePuesto@gmail.com', 'Mi nombre');
                //Esta línea es por si queréis enviar copia a alguien (dirección y, opcionalmente, nombre)
                // $mail->AddReplyTo('replyto@correoquesea.com','El de la réplica');
                //Y, ahora sí, definimos el destinatario (dirección y, opcionalmente, nombre)
                $mail->AddAddress('EmailAlQueQuieroEnviar', 'El Destinatario');
                //Definimos el tema del email
                $mail->Subject = 'Esto es un correo de prueba';
                //Para enviar un correo formateado en HTML lo cargamos con la siguiente función. Si no, puedes meterle directamente una cadena de texto.
                // $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('correomaquetado.html'), dirname(ruta_al_archivo));
                //Y por si nos bloquean el contenido HTML (algunos correos lo hacen por seguridad) una versión alternativa en texto plano (también será válida para lectores de pantalla)
                $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
                $mail->Body = 'Hello, this is my message.';
                echo (extension_loaded('openssl')?'SSL loaded':'SSL not loaded')."\n"; 
                //Enviamos el correo
                if(!$mail->Send()) {
                echo "Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                } else {

                echo "Enviado!";
                }
```

Y mi error que me da al ejecutarlo es este:

SSL loaded

> 2018-03-22 23:03:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP
>   p79sm7875211wmf.34 - gsmtp
>  2018-03-22 23:03:52 CLIENT ->
>   SERVER: EHLO localhost
>  2018-03-22 23:03:52 SERVER -> CLIENT:
>   250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [84.121.33.176]250-SIZE
>   35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250
>   SMTPUTF8
>  2018-03-22 23:03:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
>   2018-03-22 23:03:53 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start
>   TLS
>  SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
>  2018-03-22
>   23:03:53 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
>  2018-03-22 23:03:53 
>   2018-03-22 23:03:53 
>  SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
>  Error:
>   SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Aqui comentan que podría ser el caso no tener habilitado ssl. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477766/phpmailer-smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host

Comment: verifica si tienes la extensión SSL habilitada en php

Comment: los que tengan problema con la conexión smtp , lo que tienen que hacer es descargar la librería phpmailer 6.0 y listo. suerte!

Answer (score 3):

Te dejo la manera que uso yo para mandar correos por gmail

```
<?php
//Load composer's autoloader
require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'); 

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;// TCP port to connect to
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Username ='EmailQueHePuesto@gmail.com'; //Email para enviar
$mail->Password = 'ContraseñaDelEmailQueHePuesto'; //Su password
//Agregar destinatario
$mail->setFrom('EmailQueHePuesto@gmail.com', 'Mi nombre');
$mail->AddAddress('EmailAlQueQuieroEnviar@gmail.com');//A quien mandar email
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;  
$mail->Mailer = "smtp"; 


    //Content
$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML


$mail->Subject = 'PRUEBA 6';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Error al enviar email';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Mail enviado correctamente';
}
```

Espero te pueda ayudar

Comment: Geniaaal! Me ha servido a la perfección he recibido el correo.. Aunque sigo con el run run en la cabeza del por que no me dejaba a mi con el código que tenía..si es por que hacia más requires de lo debido o porqué xd pero buenoo haha muchas gracias!

Comment: por nada y a ti no te resultaba por que no tenias la parte 'ssl' bien configurada saludes

Comment: A mi no me ha funcionado...
Me regresa: SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido. (0) SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
<br /> Alguna idea?

Comment: Debes revisar los permisos que tiene tu correo

Answer (score 0):

recuerda que primero tienes que habilitar tu correo de google para que permita el acceso a aplicaciones menos seguras,

luego de acceder a tu cuenta de gmail ingresa en el siguiente link

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

alli destilda esa opcion.

una vez hecho esto toca verificar solamente que el usuario y la contraseña esten bien, tienes bien el código (servidor smpt, protocolo seguridad, puerto) por lo que veo, si esto no funciona trata de buscarte la libreria de otro repositorio.

puedes probar con esta

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;//587 or 465
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "EmailQueHePuesto@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "tu contraseña";
$mail->SetFrom("EmailQueHePuesto@gmail.com");
```

a ver que tal :D

Answer (score 0):

creo que deberias quitar el 2 de este codigo

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

y poner 0 asi lo desactivas y poner el puerto 25